# apt not working Ubuntu 18.04.03

Tags: apt, upgrade

Can't use apt neither for updating nor upgrading nor installing any software. I've tried with different WiFi connections, but the problem remains the same.
For update, the output is the following:

```
Err:1 http://es.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease
  409  Conflict [IP: 104.19.138.75 80]
Hit:2 http://ppa.launchpad.net/atareao/telegram/ubuntu bionic InRelease        
Hit:3 http://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/debian bionic InRelease        
Hit:4 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security InRelease              
Err:5 http://es.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates InRelease             
  409  Conflict [IP: 104.19.138.75 80]
Hit:6 http://prerelease.keybase.io/deb stable InRelease                        
Hit:7 https://repo.skype.com/deb stable InRelease                              
Hit:8 http://ppa.launchpad.net/fossfreedom/rhythmbox-plugins/ubuntu bionic InRelease
Err:9 http://es.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-backports InRelease     
  409  Conflict [IP: 104.19.138.75 80]
Hit:10 http://ppa.launchpad.net/graphics-drivers/ppa/ubuntu bionic InRelease  
Hit:11 http://ppa.launchpad.net/linuxuprising/apps/ubuntu bionic InRelease    
Hit:12 http://ppa.launchpad.net/musicbrainz-developers/stable/ubuntu bionic InRelease
Hit:13 http://ppa.launchpad.net/phoerious/keepassxc/ubuntu bionic InRelease    
Hit:14 http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/java/ubuntu bionic InRelease       
Reading package lists... Done 
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
E: The repository 'http://es.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease' is no longer signed.
E: Failed to fetch http://es.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/bionic/InRelease  409  Conflict [IP: 104.19.138.75 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://es.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/bionic-updates/InRelease  409  Conflict [IP: 104.19.138.75 80]
E: The repository 'http://es.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates InRelease' is no longer signed.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
N: Skipping acquire of configured file 'contrib/binary-i386/Packages' as repository 'http://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/debian bionic InRelease' doesn't support architecture 'i386'
E: Failed to fetch http://es.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/bionic-backports/InRelease  409  Conflict [IP: 104.19.138.75 80]
E: The repository 'http://es.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-backports InRelease' is no longer signed.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

And for upgrading, the following:

```
Err:1 http://es.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease
  409  Conflict [IP: 104.19.138.75 80]
Hit:2 http://ppa.launchpad.net/atareao/telegram/ubuntu bionic InRelease        
Hit:3 http://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/debian bionic InRelease        
Hit:4 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security InRelease              
Err:5 http://es.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates InRelease             
  409  Conflict [IP: 104.19.138.75 80]
Hit:6 http://prerelease.keybase.io/deb stable InRelease                        
Hit:7 https://repo.skype.com/deb stable InRelease                              
Hit:8 http://ppa.launchpad.net/fossfreedom/rhythmbox-plugins/ubuntu bionic InRelease
Err:9 http://es.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-backports InRelease     
  409  Conflict [IP: 104.19.138.75 80]
Hit:10 http://ppa.launchpad.net/graphics-drivers/ppa/ubuntu bionic InRelease  
Hit:11 http://ppa.launchpad.net/linuxuprising/apps/ubuntu bionic InRelease    
Hit:12 http://ppa.launchpad.net/musicbrainz-developers/stable/ubuntu bionic InRelease
Hit:13 http://ppa.launchpad.net/phoerious/keepassxc/ubuntu bionic InRelease    
Hit:14 http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/java/ubuntu bionic InRelease       
Reading package lists... Done 
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
E: The repository 'http://es.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease' is no longer signed.
E: Failed to fetch http://es.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/bionic/InRelease  409  Conflict [IP: 104.19.138.75 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://es.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/bionic-updates/InRelease  409  Conflict [IP: 104.19.138.75 80]
E: The repository 'http://es.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates InRelease' is no longer signed.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
N: Skipping acquire of configured file 'contrib/binary-i386/Packages' as repository 'http://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/debian bionic InRelease' doesn't support architecture 'i386'
E: Failed to fetch http://es.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/bionic-backports/InRelease  409  Conflict [IP: 104.19.138.75 80]
E: The repository 'http://es.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-backports InRelease' is no longer signed.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

Any idea as to how to fix this issue?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

The same thing happens to me, I have changed from Spain to the main one and it works;). Regards.

---

A mi me pasa lo mismo, he cambiado de España al principal y funciona ;). Saludos.